# Windows Server 2008 gpo links

Tags: windows-server-2008

What are the step-by-step procedures to link a single user account to a GPO. I want to link a GPO at the account level. I have looked in the GPMC and I cannot discover how to make this configuration.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't link a GPO directly to a user or computer. You link a GPO to an OU where the user or computer account "lives", or to the domain if the user or computer account are in the default Users or Computers containers. You can use Security Filtering on the GPO to apply it to a specific user or computer account.

Comment: Item Level Targeting can also accomplish this, preferably by putting the user in a Security Group, but it's not available for all GPO's.  ILT allows multiple settings in a single GPO, a single drive map GPO for example, where Security Filtering would require separate GPO's. Security Filtering can be simpler.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733022.aspx